# Block REST clients from using insecure https connection to my spring boot REST api

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, curl, https, ssl-certificate

I have created a REST API using Spring boot web(2.7.9). It accepts an empty POST request(just POC purpose) and returns a String response.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1")
public class Endpoint {

  @PostMapping("/start")
  public ResponseEntity<String> start(){
    System.out.println("Came to start method");
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Ok response");
  }
}
```

its accessible over http and gives 200 as expected

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://endpointserver.mayanktests.in:8981/api/v1/start'
```

(endpointserver.mayanktests.in  mapped to 127.0.0.1 in hosts file)

Now I wish to convert it to HTTPS. I create a local Root CA in my system using openSSL and create a server certificate signed from this CA. I imported the server certificate and key to Keystore

```
server.port=8981
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=******
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
```

as expected now the previous curl command failed. Also changing the scheme to HTTPS gave the below error

*curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.*

this worked when I gave the -cacert option giving my rootCA.pem file location.

```
curl  --cacert rootCA.pem --location --request POST 'https://endpointserver.mayanktests.in:8981/api/v1/start'
```

However i can also make it work with -k option (insecure)

```
curl  -k --location --request POST 'https://endpointserver.mayanktests.in:8981/api/v1/start'
```

**So my questions**

> Why is the client even allowed to continue with the connection if it does not trust the CA?

**And then my main concern**

> How to block such clients from accessing my HTTPS APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't block a client that does not trust your site from calling it. If they want to take the risk then that's their decision. A browser can indicate to the user that the site is not trusted and Postman will give a warning.

If a calling client decides to trust you, that's their call.

However, a Java client will not setup an SSL connection to an untrusted server (unless coded to ignore trust issues). I expect other languages behave in the same way. This provides protection to the clients.

If you want to trust clients then there are mechanisms like [client certificates](https://blog.codecentric.de/x-509-client-certificates-with-spring-security)

Comment: "mechanisms like client certificates".. . this means using 2 way ssl, right? Client validates the server certificate and server validates the client certificate

Comment: Technically SSL is always 2-way. The mechanism of server AND CLIENT certificates is usually called ‘mutual authentication’ - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326574/An-Introduction-to-Mutual-SSL-Authentication

Comment: A related aspect which I did not mention is that if Java does not trust a server cert it will not set up an SSL connection to said server. Adding to my answer.